# Using foreach loop in view to iterate over a field from a controller in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, controller

I'm trying to iterate over an IList stored in a field in a controller in my ASP.NET MVC4 project. I'm trying to do this in one of my views, to be able to generate HTML elements that correspond with some information gathered through a search query. The code can be seen below.

### THE CONTROLLER

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public static int MovieHits;
    public static int PeopleHits;
    public static IList<Model.MovieDto> Movies;
    public static IList<Model.PersonDto> People;

public ActionResult SearchResults(string input)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Search";
        ViewBag.Message = "Your search returned the following match(es).";

        var results = Model.ModelController.UniversalSearch(input);

        Movies = results.MovieListForUser;
        People = results.PersonListForUser;
        MovieHits = Movies.Count;
        PeopleHits = People.Count;

        return View();
    }
```

### THE VIEW

```
        <div id="movieResults">
            @foreach (var movie in HomeController.Movies)
            {
                <span class="movieResult">@movie.Title</span><br/>
            }
        </div>
```

The problem is that I get a compiling error in my browser when it tries to generate the HTML. The error message can be seen below, but be warned; it's been translated by google from danish to english, but from the looks of it, it looks largely understandable =P

### THE ERROR

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required by the processing of this request. Read the following details about the error and make the necessary changes to the source code. Error on kompileringsfunktion: CS0012: The type 'Model.MovieDto' is defined in the assembly that is not referenced. Add a reference to the assembly 'Model, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null'. Source Error:

```
Line 20: <td> 
Line 21: <div id="movieResults">
Line 22: @ foreach (var movie inHomeController.Movies)
Line 23: { 
Line 24: <span class="movieResult"> @ movie.Title < / span> <br/>
```

> Detailed output:

```
    C: \ Program Files (x86) \ IIS Express> "C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ csc.exe" / t: library / utf8output / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 2296c65a \ 68000ed7_61f2ce01 \ WebGrease.dll "/ R:" C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 27f75d7a \ 0852d4d4_61f2ce01 \ EntityFramework.dll "/ R:" C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 5496f055 \ 42f708d7_61f2ce01 \ Antlr3.Runtime.dll " / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 0ee8ac00 \ fe53add5_61f2ce01 \ System.Web.Http.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ App_global.asax.of7azw0j.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 998cd3c3 \ f48cb7d5_61f2ce01 \ System.Web.Http.OData.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ c455315f \ d0673bd4_61f2ce01 \ DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET / R: "C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ Mscorlib.dll" / R: "C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.Net \ assembly \ GAC_MSIL \ System \ v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089 \ System.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP . NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 07cc8738 \ 3289a6d4_61f2ce01 \ DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll "/ R:" C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 33bc8f69 \ 9b5d66bd_4df8ce01 \ nunit.framework.dll "/ R:" C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 93c58068 \ 93b2a5d5_61f2ce01 \ System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll " / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 2f2e565f \ 5ed196d6_61f2ce01 \ Newtonsoft.Json.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 3ca568a6 \ 56e0bed5_61f2ce01 \ System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 2d57ee1b \ 804ef2d5_61f2ce01 \ Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll" / R: "C : \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 6d3f6044 \ 23229fd5_61f2ce01 \ System.Web.Optimization.dll" / R: "C : \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 895f125b \ 5996f043_56f8ce01 \ Webclient.dll " / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ ebbe30cd \ 47e537d6_61f2ce01 \ Microsoft.Data.OData.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 51baa225 \ 4f2d9ad4_61f2ce01 \ DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ cd36e272 \ f779c0d6_61f2ce01 \ System.Spatial.dll" / R: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 96b97b00 \ 3ebd2ed4_61f2ce01 \ DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll " / Out: "C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ App_Web_searchresults.cshtml.a8d08dba.6gvjhlym.dll" / D: DEBUG / debug + / optimize-/ w : 4 / nowarn: 1659; 1699, 1701, 612, 618 / warnaserror-"C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ App_Web_searchresults.cshtml.a8d08dba.6gvjhlym .0. cs "" C: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ App_Web_searchresults.cshtml.a8d08dba.6gvjhlym.1.cs " 


Microsoft (R) Visual C # 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 

for Microsoft (R). NET Framework 4.5 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 

c: \ Users \ Emil \ Documents \ ITU \ 3 Semester \ BDSA Examn Project 2013 \ bdsa-project-2013 \ Program \ SSMDB \ WebClient \ Views \ Home \ SearchResults.cshtml (22,18): error CS0012: The type 'Model.MovieDto' is defined in the assembly that is not referenced to. Add a reference to the assembly 'Model, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null'. 
c: \ Users \ Emil \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ Temporary ASP.NET Files \ root \ 8eddbb6c \ 32280fad \ assembly \ dl3 \ 895f125b \ 5996f043_56f8ce01 \ Webclient.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error) 
c: \ Users \ Emil \ Documents \ ITU \ 3 Semester \ BDSA Examn Project 2013 \ bdsa-project-2013 \ Program \ SSMDB \ WebClient \ Views \ Home \ SearchResults.cshtml (24,54): error CS1061: 'Model.MovieDto' does not contain a definition for 'Title', and there was not found an extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'Model.MovieDto' (are you missing a "using' directive or an assemblyreference?)
```

I tried re-adding the reference to the Model class (which is located within the sollution but in another project. I'm new to both Razor and ASP.NET, so I'm kind of lost here. I reckon it might be an error in my Web.config file or an error in my ASP.NET temp files, but trying to solve the issue through these two sizes have gotten be nowhere. And then again, since I am very new to this, it might also be as simple as me doing something completely wrong. Thanks in advance, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your error try to add assembly where dto classes declared to compilation assemblies in web.config (see [Fixing Error CS0012](http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/mvc-error-cs0012/)). But...

Usage of static controller fields to pass data from controller to view is not very good idea. How you are going to handle multiple simultaneous requests? So, use `ViewBag` or create appropriate model and pass it to view:

```
public class SearchResultModel
{
    public IList<Model.MovieDto> Movies { get; set; }
    public IList<Model.PersonDto> People { get; set; }
}
```

Create and pass it

```
public ActionResult SearchResults(string input)
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    ViewBag.Message = "Your search returned the following match(es).";

    var results = Model.ModelController.UniversalSearch(input);

    var model = new SearchResultModel {
       Movies = results.MovieListForUser,
       People = results.PersonListForUser
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model Your.Namespace.SearchResultModel

...    
<td> 
<div id="movieResults">
@foreach (var movie Model.Movies) { 
    <span class="movieResult"> @movie.Title </span><br/>
}
<span>Total movie hits: @Model.Movies.Count</span>
...
```

Each web request will result in separate model creation.

Comment: First off, thanks for the tip with getting rid of the static fields, that's the fruit of late-night-coding and next to no sleep for a week. Good thing it was discovered before hand-in on monday :) Next, I tried adding the Model to the pages namespace section of the web.config file, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @AbaccusX consider also to read [How to Pass Data From a Controller to a View](http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/mvc-data-controller-view/) article, which describes several ways to pass data to view

Comment: @AbaccusX your error can be fixed by adding assembly where model classes declared to list of assemblies - see [here](http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/mvc-error-cs0012/).

Comment: Thank you very much for an elaborate and patient handling of my question. The first article you linked to is great and very informative. The second post solved my problem beautifully. Too bad my rep is too low to give you an up. But thanks again, you just saved several hours of melancholy about not meeting my deadline on monday :)

Comment: @AbaccusX glad I helped you :) Keep learning and soon you'll become professional!